# Best Database Storage Method

Tags: php, mysql, database, normalization, organization

My software (written in PHP) allows users to use an HTML form to enter information for their 'Resume'. There are several different elements of this 'resume' including the user's education,  work history, awards, cover letter, and etc. Each element is unique in the data it contains. For example, education requires fields such as graduation year, school name, degree, etc.

My question is, what would be the best approach to store the resume data in a mySQL database? My current choices are:

- Create individual tables for each resume element (resume_education, resume_awards, etc.)
- Use a single table for all elements of the resume and insert the element data in the form of multi-dimensional arrays. (IE: one table that holds resume data with columns such as education, workhistory, blah blah. Data in education or similar field would be compiled into an array such as ("grad_year"=>"1990", "school_name"=>"Cool School") or something similar where the usage of indicating characters denotes a new field).

The first choice offers an ease of maintenance and coding whereas the second choice would seem to offer a substantial decrease in backup and maybe load times, and database maintenance. Maybe there is an altogether better approach? What would you recommend ?

Comment: Actually your pro-and-con assessments are exactly reversed!

Comment: Well I would see multiple tables as being easier to maintain rather than attempting to traverse multiple multi-dimensional arrays within a single table. But I do see where you could be coming from as I am unsure about either method's effect on load time.

Comment: I wouldn't be concerned about load times for something this simple.  Multiple tables with joins is a good option.

Comment: Well this is just a single element of an entire user's profile which will need to support many users and entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd go for multiple tables, but not named tables something more generic.

Eg. tables

```
resume_section
id,name
1,personal details
2,education
3,work history

resume_section_attributes
id,resume_section_id,name
1,1,name
2,1,phone
3,1,email
4,2,school_name
5,2,grad_year
6,3,company_name
7,3,number_of_years

user_resume
id,user_id,resume_section_attribute_id,value
1,99,1,My Name
2,99,2,12345678
```

Now when you want to build a users resume you can go straight to the user resume table and get all their details and join with the attributes table for the attribute names etc.  You could change the order of attrs for display, easily add new ones.  Set them as required or not. Set limits for the number of phone numbers or something.  The possibilities for extending are endless.

Comment: After reading [this](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/07/maybe-normalizing-isnt-normal.html) I am trying to avoid fully normalizing. Thanks for making me remember scalability, as deleting specific items from a single row containing an array with a length in excess of 5-10 items would be a pain in the ass.

Comment: Will you be dealing with that sort of volume?  Plus it really depends on your data.  Do you want to hardcode a phone number and mobile or allow the user to add as many as they like.  This comment sums it up, The normalized model allows for n number of user phone numbers, screen names, affiliation and work history. It also does not care about the order of those items.

Comment: Yes, I am attempting to prepare for a large volume of users. I agree with what you're saying. But I don't see how using resume_phoneNumber as a table could be a negative? I could store multiple phone numbers for one user, granted I don't set my User ID column as UNIQUE, correct?

Comment: Actually that is probably worse.  You talking many tables for a single resume now, you'll need to index them all and query across all of them.  What if you want to add a new field? Create a new table and do all the hardcoding to get it working.  Imagine you just add a new attribute, set its name, which section its under and its order within that section and bang its there to be filled out.

Comment: Hmm, in that case, I guess I don't fully understand your example code. Would you mind taking this to a chat with me?

Comment: I just provided a generic table idea, you would need to write the code.  But what I'm saying is if you approach it from a generic point of view it will make it easier in the future.  Plus you might just learn alot and have a nice piece of software to show off.

Comment: If you want an example of the extreme end of the generic scale have a look at Drupals Nodes and Content types.  You can essentially create anything with these.  I don't use drupal but I've read about how they do it.

Comment: I have to thank you, I have never fully understood database normalization until I figured out your table layout. You have saved me a lot of future hassle. Thanks a lot, man!

Comment: No problem!  Like those articles said its not always the best option.  But I think this application is ideal to learn how to do it, it's not overly complicated and you'll be able to reuse the ideas in the future when required to allow for unlimited phone numbers or contacts etc.  Try not to hardcode anything in your code so when you add a new attribute under personal details for example it will automatically come up in your form without any extra code.  Eg.  construct the form from the db.

Answer (score 1):

Option 2 is clearly and unequivocally wrong.  If you're not going to decompose your data into rows and columns and follow *at least* the first couple of rules of data normalization then there's no reason to use a relational database (you could use XML documents in file system folders).

Option 1 is probably most correct.  In the event that all elements are expected to be present in all resumes, and no elements repeat within a resume, then you could actually have one table for the entire resume, with each field in its own column.  Since I don't imagine that those conditions are met (work history and education should probably be repeatable elements, for instance) then separate tables per element is the correct choice.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely go with option 1.  Good database design is vital, and good database design involves   normalizing your data which is only possible if you model  distinct entities with their own tables.

Take a look at [this article on database normalization](http://www.devshed.com/c/a/MySQL/An-Introduction-to-Database-Normalization/), which has a good discussion of the concepts involved.

Comment: Thank you for that link, I will take another look at that (I saw this a few months back as well). Sorry accidentally hit enter, anyway, as far a the design of the database itself is concerned, I see no impact on the design from the content of the columns itself, right?